pip install openbabel failing
I am facing an issue installing openbabel in windows for python but its failing with below error. Can someone please help?
C:\Users\X265065>pip install openbabel
WARNING: Skipping C:\Users\X265065\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pillow-10.2.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping C:\Users\X265065\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pillow-10.2.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
Collecting openbabel
Using cached openbabel-3.1.1.1.tar.gz (82 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: openbabel
Building wheel for openbabel (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [66 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
Warning: invalid version number '3.1.1.1'.
Guessing Open Babel location:
- include_dirs: ['C:\Program Files\Python311\include', 'C:\Program Files\Python311\Include', '/usr/local/include/openbabel3']
- library_dirs: ['C:\Program Files\Python311\libs', 'C:\Program Files\Python311', 'C:\Program Files\Python311\PCbuild\amd64', '/usr/local/lib']
building 'openbabel._openbabel' extension
swigging openbabel\openbabel-python.i to openbabel\openbabel-python_wrap.cpp
swig.exe -python -c++ -small -O -templatereduce -naturalvar "-IC:\Program Files\Python311\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python311\Include" -I/usr/local/include/openbabel3 -o openbabel\openbabel-python_wrap.cpp openbabel\openbabel-python.i
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(246) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\babelconfig.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(248) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\data.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(249) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\obutil.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(250) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\math\vector3.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(252) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\math\matrix3x3.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(253) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\math\transform3d.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(254) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\math\spacegroup.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(256) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\bitvec.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(260) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\base.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(262) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\generic.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(265) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\griddata.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(267) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\chains.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(268) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\typer.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(276) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\plugin.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(281) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\oberror.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(282) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\format.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(283) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\obconversion.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(284) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\obfunctions.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(295) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\elements.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(296) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\residue.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(297) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\internalcoord.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(298) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\atom.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(299) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\bond.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(300) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\reaction.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(301) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\reactionfacade.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(319) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\mol.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(326) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\ring.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(327) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\parsmart.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(328) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\alias.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(330) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\fingerprint.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(332) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\descriptor.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(343) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\forcefield.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(345) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\builder.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(346) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\op.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(348) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\chargemodel.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(351) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\phmodel.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(352) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\graphsym.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(353) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\isomorphism.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(354) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\query.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(355) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\canon.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(357) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\stereo\stereo.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(361) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\rotor.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(363) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\rotamer.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(364) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\spectrophore.h'
openbabel\openbabel-python.i(435) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\obiter.h'
openbabel\stereo.i(1) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\stereo\tetranonplanar.h'
openbabel\stereo.i(2) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\stereo\tetraplanar.h'
openbabel\stereo.i(3) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\stereo\tetrahedral.h'
openbabel\stereo.i(4) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\stereo\cistrans.h'
openbabel\stereo.i(5) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\stereo\squareplanar.h'
openbabel\stereo.i(6) : Error: Unable to find 'openbabel\stereo\bindings.h'
  Error: SWIG failed. Is Open Babel installed?
  You may need to manually specify the location of Open Babel include and library directories. For example:
    python setup.py build_ext -I/usr/local/include/openbabel3 -L/usr/local/lib
    python setup.py install
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for openbabel
Running setup.py clean for openbabel
Failed to build openbabel
ERROR: Could not build wheels for openbabel, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
WARNING: Skipping C:\Users\X265065\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pillow-10.2.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping C:\Users\X265065\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pillow-10.2.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping C:\Users\X265065\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pillow-10.2.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
I have installed openbabel 3.1 software also.

Have you read the entire error message yourself? Have you understood what it says?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Make sure that your python version is compatible with openbable package.Check if your setup tools or pip is last version.
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools pip

Install dependencies with:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libopenbabel-dev

If those solutions don't work, uninstall and install openbable.
